# onResponse() of Retrofit2 is working inproperly

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, response

I am trying to get data from server. I wrote network model but some guys advised to use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ or http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/. I used both of them but problem is not solved. I have authorization activity where I could get token in order to access to other datum. So, after authorization I go to AddressActivity where I should get user data(name, zipcode etc..) and those data should appear on my activity recyclerview. But it does not happen. Nevertheless, I am getting data. I checked it on **OkHttp.** Problem with appearance. I put Toast messages after every **method** and **if&else statement** in order to check which part is not working. So, I figure out problem with **onResponse(..)**, because I am getting **Log** and my **Toast message** in **onFailure(..)**. But if I don't authorize and try to get Addresses, the else part of onResponse(..) works.

**IService.kt:**

```
package com.example.ganz.afex.net

import com.example.ganz.afex.models.Address_Network_Model
import com.example.ganz.afex.net.pojo.me.ResponseMe
import com.example.ganz.afex.net.pojo.re_and_log.*
import com.example.ganz.afex.net.pojo.update_password.RequestUpdatePass
import com.example.ganz.afex.net.pojo.update_password.ResponseUpdatePassword
import com.example.ganz.afex.net.pojo.update_profile.RequestUpdateProfile
import com.example.ganz.afex.net.pojo.update_profile.ResponseUpdateProfile
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.POST
import retrofit2.http.PUT

interface IService {

    @POST("authorize")
    fun login(@Body login: RequestLogin): Call<ResponseLogin>

    @POST("accesstoken")
    fun getToken(@Body request: GetAccessTokenRequest): Call<GetAccessTokenResponse>

    @GET("me")
    fun getMe(): Call<ResponseMe>

    @GET("addresses/all")
    fun getAllAddresses(): Call<List<Address_Network_Model>>
}
```

**Recyc_Adapter_Addresses**:

```
package com.example.ganz.afex.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.ganz.afex.R;
import com.example.ganz.afex.models.Address_Network_Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Recyc_Adapter_Addresses extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recyc_Adapter_Addresses.MyViewHolder> {


    private Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = Recyc_Adapter_Addresses.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<Address_Network_Model> mAddrNetwork;



    public Recyc_Adapter_Addresses(Context mContext, List<Address_Network_Model> mAddrNetwork) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mAddrNetwork = mAddrNetwork;
    }

    public Recyc_Adapter_Addresses() {
        mAddrNetwork = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_addresses, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tv_cust_city_id.setText(mAddrNetwork.get(position).getCityId());
        holder.tv_cust_address.setText(mAddrNetwork.get(position).getAddress());
        holder.tv_cust_zipcode.setText(mAddrNetwork.get(position).getZipCode());
        holder.tv_cust_phone_1.setText(mAddrNetwork.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.tv_cust_phone_2.setText(mAddrNetwork.get(position).getPhone2());
        holder.tv_cust_map_lat.setText(mAddrNetwork.get(position).getMapLat());
        holder.tv_cust_map_lng.setText(mAddrNetwork.get(position).getMapLng());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return mAddrNetwork.size();
    }

    public void addAddress(Address_Network_Model addrNetwork) {
            Log.d(TAG, addrNetwork.getAddress());
            mAddrNetwork.add(addrNetwork);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_cust_city_id;
        TextView tv_cust_address;
        TextView tv_cust_zipcode;
        TextView tv_cust_phone_1;
        TextView tv_cust_phone_2;
        TextView tv_cust_map_lat;
        TextView tv_cust_map_lng;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_cust_city_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_customer_city_id);
            tv_cust_address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_customer_address);
            tv_cust_zipcode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_customer_zipcode);
            tv_cust_phone_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_customer_phone);
            tv_cust_phone_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_customer_phone2);
            tv_cust_map_lat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_customer_map_lat);
            tv_cust_map_lng = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_customer_map_lng);
        }
    }
}
```

**Address_Network_Model:**

```
        package com.example.ganz.afex.models;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Address_Network_Model {

    @SerializedName("city_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer cityId;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("zip_code")
    @Expose
    private String zipCode;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    private String phone;
    @SerializedName("phone2")
    @Expose
    private String phone2;
    @SerializedName("map_lat")
    @Expose
    private Integer mapLat;
    @SerializedName("map_lng")
    @Expose
    private Integer mapLng;

    public Integer getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(Integer cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhone2() {
        return phone2;
    }

    public void setPhone2(String phone2) {
        this.phone2 = phone2;
    }

    public Integer getMapLat() {
        return mapLat;
    }

    public void setMapLat(Integer mapLat) {
        this.mapLat = mapLat;
    }

    public Integer getMapLng() {
        return mapLng;
    }

    public void setMapLng(Integer mapLng) {
        this.mapLng = mapLng;
    }
}
```

**AddressActivity:**

```
package com.example.ganz.afex.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ganz.afex.R;
import com.example.ganz.afex.adapters.Recyc_Adapter_Addresses;
import com.example.ganz.afex.models.Address_Network_Model;
import com.example.ganz.afex.net.NetworkManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static android.util.Config.LOGD;

public class AddressActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private List<Address_Network_Model> addressList;
    private Recyc_Adapter_Addresses myAdapterAddress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_address);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NetworkManager mNetworkManager = new NetworkManager(this);

       // if (mNetworkManager != null) {

            Toast.makeText(AddressActivity.this, "I guess NetworkManager is Not Null..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Call<List<Address_Network_Model>> listCall = mNetworkManager.getService().getAllAddresses();

            listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Address_Network_Model>>()

            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Address_Network_Model>> call,
                                       Response<List<Address_Network_Model>> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddressActivity.this, "I guess onResponce is working..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddressActivity.this, "I guess IF STATEMENT is working..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        addressList = response.body();

                        for (int i = 0; i < addressList.size(); i++) {
                            Address_Network_Model addrNetwork = addressList.get(i);
                            myAdapterAddress.addAddress(addrNetwork);
                            myAdapterAddress.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(AddressActivity.this, "I guess the circle is working..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddressActivity.this, "I guess the circle is NOT working..1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        int sc = response.code();
                        switch (sc) {

                        }
                        Toast.makeText(AddressActivity.this, "I guess the circle is NOT working..2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Address_Network_Model>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("MyTag", "This is NOT running");
                    Toast.makeText(AddressActivity.this, "I guess here is Failure..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
      /*  } else {
            Toast.makeText(AddressActivity.this, "Here is NullPointerException!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        RecyclerView myRecyc_Addresses = findViewById(R.id.rv_customer_address);
        myAdapterAddress = new Recyc_Adapter_Addresses(this, new ArrayList<Address_Network_Model>());
        myRecyc_Addresses.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        myRecyc_Addresses.setAdapter(myAdapterAddress);
    }

    public void gotoAddingAddress (View v) {
        Intent intentAddingAdd = new Intent (this, AddressAddingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentAddingAdd);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**NetworkManager:**

```
package com.example.ganz.afex.net;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

import com.example.ganz.afex.Config;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.readystatesoftware.chuck.ChuckInterceptor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class NetworkManager {
    private static NetworkManager instance = null;
    private IService service;
    private ConnectivityManager connectionService;

    public NetworkManager() {
    }

    public NetworkManager(final Context context) {
        connectionService = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Config.TOKEN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String value = preferences.getString(Config.TOKEN, "");
                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader(Config.HEADER_KEY, value).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        };

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .create();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .addInterceptor(new ChuckInterceptor(context))
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl("http://api.site.com/v1/")
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(IService.class);

    }

    public static NetworkManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new NetworkManager(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        NetworkInfo info = connectionService.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return info != null;
    }

    public IService getService() {
        return service;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
**Log:**

```
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 04:43:58 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    Set-Cookie: advanced-backend=e0c8fjbdmnh4fgt8r21jomvk99; path=/; HttpOnly
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    X-Powered-By: Your Company <www.mywebsite.com>
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Expose-Headers: 
    Set-Cookie: _identity-backend=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: _csrf=X7bdxzchUN3XG4UWYEIdTx7931_y_TL_; path=/; HttpOnly
08-27 09:44:03.985 6259-6850/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 552
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
08-27 09:44:03.990 6259-6850/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/OkHttp: {
        "status": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "city_id": 1,
                "address": "some address",
                "zip_code": "zip_code",
                "phone": "99891981651",
                "phone2": "99866518413",
                "map_lat": 654654,
                "map_lng": 65465500
            },
            {
                "city_id": 2,
                "address": "some address2",
                "zip_code": "zip_code2",
                "phone": "31213",
                "phone2": "321321",
                "map_lat": 32165500,
                "map_lng": 165850000000
            }
        ]
    }
    <-- END HTTP (552-byte body)
08-27 09:44:03.993 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation E/MyTag: This is NOT running
08-27 09:44:04.428 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/ViewRootImpl@9529ad8[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0} changed=false
08-27 09:44:05.758 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/ViewRootImpl@691b290[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
08-27 09:44:05.759 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/InputEventReceiver: channel 'e2defff Toast (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
    channel 'e2defff Toast (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
08-27 09:44:05.811 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/ViewRootImpl@fbaf254[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{966f5fd V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} TM=true MM=false
08-27 09:44:05.812 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation V/Toast: Text: J gu in android.widget.Toast$TN@e7802f2
08-27 09:44:05.816 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/ViewRootImpl@fbaf254[Toast]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
08-27 09:44:05.841 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
08-27 09:44:05.842 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/ViewRootImpl@fbaf254[Toast]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[166,1064][554,1152] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 3348453376} changed=true
08-27 09:44:05.849 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/ViewRootImpl@fbaf254[Toast]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(166, 1064 - 554, 1152) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
08-27 09:44:07.780 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/ViewRootImpl@fbaf254[Toast]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
08-27 09:44:07.780 6259-6259/com.example.ganz.afex_with_default_navigation D/InputEventReceiver: channel '53bdff7 Toast (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
    channel '53bdff7 Toast (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
```

**UPDATE #2:**
*New Log:*

```
Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 13:03:27 GMT
          Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
          Set-Cookie: advanced-backend=r2cg25r0sojqsiubadta7019gj; path=/; HttpOnly
          Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
          Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
          Pragma: no-cache
          X-Powered-By: Your Company <www.mywebsite.com>
          Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
          Access-Control-Expose-Headers: 
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: _identity-backend=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; HttpOnly
          Set-Cookie: _csrf=FDDU3VHxYtx5PAbCLMwbyvAmYZpkE_9E; path=/; HttpOnly
          Content-Length: 35
          Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
          Connection: Keep-Alive
          Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
D/OkHttp: {
              "status": 1,
              "data": []
          }
          <-- END HTTP (35-byte body)
```

Comment: Add your log what you got in retrofit response in OnFailure?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH done

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your pojo doesn't match the Json you're receiving. In this call

```
@GET("addresses/all")
fun getAllAddresses(): Call<List<Address_Network_Model>>
```

You return a list of addresses, but the Json is different. If you want to deserialize the given Json, then you need to create another pojo which includes the status (optional actually) and the address list. Something like:

```
data class ResponseAddresses(
        @SerializedName("data")
        @Expose
        val  data: List<Address_Network_Model>
 )
```

As you can see, the pojo should match the Json hierarchy. Now, just change your retrofit call:

```
@GET("addresses/all")
fun getAllAddresses(): Call<ResponseAddresses>
```

**EDIT**

After some requests in the comments, here is a more detailed explanation.

The json shown in the logs is the following:

```
{
 "status": 1,
 "data": [
   {
     "city_id": 1,
     "address": "some address",
     "zip_code": "zip_code",
     "phone": "99891981651",
     "phone2": "99866518413",
     "map_lat": 654654,
     "map_lng": 65465500
   },
   ...
  ]
}
```

This json is not a list of addresses. It's an object containing 2 fields - `status` and `data`. `status` is an integer and `data` is the list of addresses you are interested in.

The easiest way to get this correctly parsed is by replicating the json structure with POJOs and use it. Now I know the first time I used kotlin, but let's use java here. I'm only writing the fields.

```
class ResponseAddresses {
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Address_Network_Model> data;
    // ...
}
```

*(you can add the status field, but it's not needed if you only want the addresses)*

So what's different here? Now you have an object that has 1 field - `data` - which is the list of addresses. Now, this is way easier to map to the json you receive and retrofit has no problems doing it. The only change missing is the call for retrofit and as I stated above, you need to change the return type to `Call<ResponseAddresses>`:

```
@GET("addresses/all")
fun getAllAddresses(): Call<ResponseAddresses>
```

How are you going to get the list of addresses? Well, just access it normally in `onResponse`:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseAddresses> call,                                     
                       Response<ResponseAddresses> response) {
   if (response.isSuccessful()) {
      addressList = response.body().getData();
      // ...
   }
}
```

The main change is that you now have to call a getter - `getData()` in this example.

Comment: Sir, OP is using Java not Kotlin. He might get confused by your answer :)

Comment: That's not true... OP is using kotlin and java for pojos, which are quite easier to understand in kotlin when represented as data classes. This makes my answer also smaller. I trust that the OP can translate the simple data class to kotlin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Fred but could you give more details and show them on my code? What do you mean with "the Json is different"? And also, I know that I return a list of addresses. Because, I need size of a list for my loop to count addresses. I guess that this problem might be faced by even more people, and if you can help it would be appreciated by whole community.

Comment: Hi again @Fred. I did what you said. Your advice helped me a lot but then I faced some other issues. Such as, _type_ of my model's variables: _mapLat_ and _mapLng_. The server was giving me them in _float type_. Then I changed their type to _integer_ in server too as they are in my model now. After that I could access to the onResponse(..). But now, for loop is not working. Because, _size()_ is returning nothing. data field of json's object is also returning nothing. I think that's why size() is zero. So my question is where I made mistake or what should I do?

Comment: There's no mistake that I can see. The returned json is empty. Probably you're querying with wrong parameters or something similar. Unfortunately, you didn't post your urls in the logs, so it's hard to say what's the difference.